# else if not working in

Tags: php, cakephp

if condition matches but else if condition is not working when i insert $total_salary = 10000 and $salary_type = NO.

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $DATA = $this->data;
    $employee_salary = $this->Salary->save($DATA);
    $total_salary = $employee_salary['Salary']['salary'];
    $salary_type = $employee_salary['Salary']['salary_in_ctc'];
    echo $total_salary . $salary_type;
    if (($total_salary > 15000) && ($salary_type === 'YES')) {
        $pf_company = 1500;
        $pf_employee = 1500;
        $percent = 0.62;
        $gross_salary = ($total_salary - $pf_company);
        $base_salary = ($percent * $gross_salary);
        $HRA = ($base_salary / 2);
        $others = ($gross_salary - ($base_salary + $HRA));
        $inhand_salary = ($gross_salary - $pf_employee);
    } elseif (($total_salary < 15000) && ($salary_type === 'NO')) {
        echo'hello';
        $pf_company = 1200;
        $pf_employee = 1200;
        $percent = 0.62;
        $gross_salary = ($total_salary - $pf_company);
        $base_salary = ($percent * $gross_salary);
        $HRA = ($base_salary / 2);
        $others = ($gross_salary - ($base_salary + $HRA));
        $inhand_salary = ($gross_salary - $pf_employee);
    }
```

Comment: can you add the the output of `$total_salary` & `$salary_type`?

Comment: Total salary = 25000
Gross salary = 23500
Base Salery = 14570
HRA = 7285
Others = 1645
Inhand Salary = 22000

Comment: loop work for 1st if condition not working for else if condition. when i insert total salary 10000 and status is NO

Comment: have you checked the datatype of `$salary_type` as you are using identical matching..

Comment: @sgt we think the same way as i am considering from last 3 days on some of the question

Comment: yes datatype is string and in database VARCHAR $salary_type

Comment: first check what output come from $salary_type..

Comment: @vikramsharma i want to check both the condition true to go inside the loop || condition will false my loop condition.

Comment: can you add single quote between '15000'

Comment: `'` is not necessary. it will convert it as required.

Answer (score 0):

try to match the uppercase condition and also check for white space in you conditions.
`strtoupper(trim($salary_type))`

Answer (score -1):

The possible second issue could be:
As you are checking the datatype also in the condition `$salary_type ==='NO'` and in the post you stated you are passing $salary_type = NO. which doesn't seems to be a string type.

Please try removing one = from condition or passing NO as a string to validate the condition

Comment: i have tried both else if . you should see the documentation  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: @SurajRajput sorry for the mistake i have updated the answer.
Have you tried var_dump($salary_type); just before the condition to check what exactly the value is

Comment: both are strings  string(3) "YES"       string(5) "10000"  .

Comment: @SurajRajput what is in case of NO as you have issue in the else part

Comment: NO is the case where salary of employee . if  ctc salary YES if in hand then  NO

Comment: @SurajRajput I just pasted your code in a file and passed  $total_salary = 10000;
    $salary_type = 'NO'; and i got the below output. it seems to enter the else part and printed hello.
10000NOhello